# PHP $_POST values returning '0'

Tags: javascript, php, post

I have a `javascript` function that modifies a series of `dropdown` fields actively based on what's appended to another `dropdown`, so they're all linked.

```
function addOpt() {
    var opt = [ document.getElementById('party') , document.getElementById('bride') , document.getElementById('groom') , document.getElementById('moh') , document.getElementById('bestman') , document.getElementById('bst1') , document.getElementById('bst2') , document.getElementById('bst3') , document.getElementById('bst4') , document.getElementById('bst5') , document.getElementById('bst6') , document.getElementById('bst7') , document.getElementById('gst1') , document.getElementById('gst2') , document.getElementById('gst3') , document.getElementById('gst4') , document.getElementById('gst5') , document.getElementById('gst6') , document.getElementById('gst7') , document.getElementById('ringbearer') , document.getElementById('fg1') , document.getElementById('fg2') , document.getElementById('rd1') , document.getElementById('rd2') ];
    var addition = document.getElementById('addition').value.capitalize(true);
    var obj;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < opt.length; i++) {
        obj = document.createElement('option');
        obj.appendChild(document.createTextNode(addition));
        obj.value = addition;
        add = opt[i].appendChild(obj);
    }
}
```

The problem I have now is when I try to post these `<select>` fields to a form with method "post" all `$_POST` values return '0'. No data.

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/07Lb9oph/) I'm not sure why the post values won't return.

Comment: Fixed the fiddle because it didn't submit the code to the correct form post page.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work properly so here is the full source http://www.thereverendmichael.com/weddingparty/

Comment: Not an answer to your question but, it seems you could benefit from knowledge of [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) You could add a class to the inputs and selects and then `var opt = document.querySelectorAll('.myInputClass');`

Comment: Ah yeah for the select array, that's very handy! thank you :)

Comment: problem with the jsFiddle is it doesn't like those inline onClick. it works if you add the listeners from javascript. Second, the actual page linked is echoing the capitalize portion before the `<!DOCTYPE html>` you should stick it between the `<head></head> tags` Third,you appear to be missing the `name` attirbute for the maid of honor and the best man. Lastly,i copy-pasted your code, straight off the linked page, made a save.php that just does`<?php var_dump($_POST);`and i get it all. Dunno why you're getting 00. Couldbe your PHPcode. Check the network tab ondev tools in your browser(use F12

Comment: Yes I see the var dump worked, I wonder if it was just that javascript not being in the head of the code like you said. Thank you, the var dump worked for me too.

Comment: Could be but, even with the script tag up there it worked on my page... it's a strange error, for sure. Happy Programming

Comment: I have too much time on my hands so, [here's a new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ab6r1sk2/). It gets rid of all the inline JS. You would have to put all of the JS* in a script tag that is after the <form> tag. *not the capitalize definition

Comment: I will use this to learn more about JS :) Thank you so much! I'm still a novice so this definitely helps me progress as I'm self-taught.